# Enable anonymous access to ADFS 2.0 SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wif, adfs2.0

I have a SharePoint 2007 portal configured to authenticate againsts a STS (ADFS 2.0) using the FormsSignIn (Forms Authentication on the ADFS).  Is there any way to have a few pages living in the SharePoint portal that allow anonymous access?  I've tried checking the "Enable Anonymous Access" in the SharePoint Central Admin, and I've tried adding location sections in the web.config, but both of these still redirects to the ADFS login page.

I have re-branded the ADFS login site so it looks less generic and more like our SharePoint login page.  Should I just move those anonymous access pages out of SharePoint and into the ADFS site?

ADFS is new to me and I'm not sure what the best practices are for customizing the login process.

Thanks,

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing

Answer (score 1):

After a couple days without an answer, I re-posted this question on [SharePoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5832/enable-anonymous-access-to-adfs-2-0-sharepoint-site).  After re-enabling allow anonymous access, I was able to get to these pages.  Although, I am getting an internal error 500 for all stylesheets that are in the /Style Library/ library.  So I'm not sure if I'm that much better off.